# ERROR in src/app/hero.service.ts(2,22): error TS2305: Module '"F:/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'of'

Tags: angular, rxjs

Below are my angular `package.json` settings

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
  "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
  "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
  "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
  "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
  "@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.10",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},

"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.11"
}
```

Below is the code for HeroService component, and getting the below posted error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/Observable/of';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  constructor() { }
  getHeroes() : Observable<Hero[]> {
      return of(HEROES);
  }

}
```

error:

```
ERROR in src/app/hero.service.ts(2,22): error TS2305: Module '"F:/practice/Angular/cli/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'of'.
```

Below are a few things I tried out with no positive results:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

and

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think import path is not correct.

Try importing like following :

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

OR

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

Comment: This one works:  "import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';"

Comment: Great!! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Import from the correct place :

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Comment: but it still throws " ERROR in src/app/hero.service.ts(14,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'of'." The above answer works import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';